# Can I forward a port though the console without using a session in Putty?

Tags: putty, port-forwarding

I would like to forward a port through a console without using a session in [Putty](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html).
Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
plink -v -N -L 1234:localhost:1234 example.com
```

Comment: Thnx, `-L 1234:localhost:1234` is what I was looking for. Actually I ws not aware, that plink is a console interface for putty, so you can login with it and to the usual -ssh user@host.com:22 -i "privatekey.ppk". The whole command: `plink -ssh user@host.com:22 -i "privatekey.ppk" -L 1234:localhost:1234`

Comment: @Skip: Note that `plink` does not have terminal emulation – so it is really unsuited for "interactive" use. (For example, text editors won't work.) You should run plink only for portforwards (with `-v -N`), and keep PuTTY for everything else.

Comment: @Skip: (Also, the `-ssh` option is redundant.)